# Исключение при создании потока

Tags: c++, многопоточность, winapi, память

Мне нужно сохранить некую информацию по базовому адресу загрузки приложения. Но как только я что то записываю по первым двум байтам, у меня происходит необработанное исключение при создании потока стандартными средствами c++.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <TlHelp32.h>


void Thr()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Sleep(1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    void* image_base = reinterpret_cast<void*>(GetModuleHandleA(NULL));

    DWORD oldProtect;
    if (!VirtualProtect(image_base, 2, PAGE_READWRITE, &oldProtect))
        return false;

    ((PCHAR)image_base)[1] = 4;

    if (!VirtualProtect(image_base, 2, oldProtect, &oldProtect))
        return false;

    std::thread _thr(Thr); //вот тут происходит исключение
    _thr.detach();

    system("pause");
    return 1;
}
```

Я даже предположить не могу почему так может происходить. Но очень странно, ведь первые 2 байта приложения - это MZ сигнатура. Неужели она проверяется перед созданием потока?...

Comment: Как минимум первые два байта в файле и первые два байта в памяти — это две ну очень большие разницы...

Comment: @Harry я где то писал про 2 байта в файле?

Comment: а зачем делать запись по первым двум байтам? ("мне надо" это не ответ, это желание)

Comment: @KoVadim неужели это играет роль? Может я экспериментирую?

Comment: да да, экспериментируете. Например, на месте антивирусника я бы вырубал такое приложение, которое пытается себя пропатчить в странных местах (хотя автора jvm хотят другого, но это их проблемы)

Comment: @Harry я понимаю что MZ сигнатура важна только на стадии загрузки, тем не менее, исключение при создании потока происходит только если изменить их. И все заголовки существуют как в файле так и с исполняемом образе, они в точности проецируются по адресу загрузки

Comment: а Вы проверяли, что по адресу, где Вы пишите, действительно находятся буковки MZ?

Comment: @KoVadim меня иногда удивляют комментаторы данного форума.... Один пишет что MZ сигнатура существует только в файле, другой спрашивает проверял ли я что там MZ сигнатура...

Comment: ну мало чего. в линуксе сложно проверить подобные вещи.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ох. ну почему люди никогда не проверяют нормально коды возврата? там сколько полезной информации бывает. Давайте перепишем немного приложение, что бы оно нам помогло.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <TlHelp32.h>


void Thr()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Sleep(1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    void* image_base = reinterpret_cast<void*>(GetModuleHandleA(NULL));

    DWORD oldProtect;
    if (!VirtualProtect(image_base, 2, PAGE_READWRITE, &oldProtect))
        return false;

    ((PCHAR)image_base)[1] = 4;

    if (!VirtualProtect(image_base, 2, oldProtect, &oldProtect))
        return false;

    try {
    std::thread _thr(Thr); //вот тут происходит исключение
    _thr.detach();
    }
    catch(...) { puts("да, случилось, но и так знаем"); }
    printf("error = %d\n", GetLastError()); // Вот это нас и интересует!
    system("pause");
    return 1;
}
```

запускаем и что видим? выдает `error = 193`. Открываем Error Lookup (стандартная утилита, идет с студией, даже с меню Tools можно открыть), вбиваем туда и получаем "%1 is not a valid Win32 application.".

Ну да, логично. Мы же повредили самый базовый заголовок. Но почему это так важно? Скорее всего, потому что когда создается новый поток, операционная система должна создать для него "инфраструктуру" - стек, какие то внутренние записи, таблицу импорта подгрузить. А вот это все как раз можно прочитать в заголовке файла. Не хранить же его в десяти местах. Там же можно найти адреса таблиц импорта. Да, все это уже находится в значительно дальше, чем MZ, но код, который читает это все должен быть уверен, что он читает то, что нужно.

Comment: Как догадки, что конкретно системе надо прочитать из ехе, это размер стека по умолчанию и TLS callbacks. С первым можно попытаться побороться, передав явно размер стека в явный вызов  `CreateThread`, с последним -- используя `DisableThreadLibraryCalls(GetModuleHandle(NULL))`